# Enter key is not working for Select list on VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Created a search Visualforce page. I associated the **enter key** to the search command button(**Search**), so whenever user press the enter button it should search the page.

But the issue is it's not working on any select list only working on input text/number.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Here is the my Visualforce page :

```
<apex:page controller="OppSearchController" docType="html-5.0">

<script>
/* function executed when a key is pressed in any of the input boxes */
function keypress(ev)
{

if (window.event)
{
ev=window.event;
}

/* which key was pressed ? */
var keyCode;
if (ev.keyCode)
{
keyCode=ev.keyCode;
}
else
{
keyCode=ev.charCode;
}

var result=true;

if (keyCode == 13)
{
/* it was the return key - find the save button */
var ele=document.getElementById('{!$Component.btnSearch}');

ele.click();

result=false;
}

return result;
}
</script>
    <apex:form>
        <table>
            <td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: .5em;"><B>Amount</B>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <apex:input type="number" value="{!srAmount}"
                    style="width:100px" onkeypress="return keypress(event);" /></td>

            <td style="padding-right: 10px;"><B>Stage</B> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <apex:selectList id="stage" value="{!srStage}" size="1"
                    onkeypress="return keypress(event);">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Stages}">
                    </apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectList></td>
            <td style="padding-right: 10px;"><B>Category</B>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <apex:selectList id="category"
                    value="{!srforcast}" size="1" onkeypress="return keypress(event);">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Category}">
                    </apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectList></td>


        </table>

        <br />
        <br />
        <table align="center">

            <td><apex:commandButton value="Search" id="btnSearch"
                    action="{!Search}" styleclass="searchByMe" /></td>

            <td><apex:commandButton value="Clear" action="{!clear}" /></td>


        </table>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Search Result">
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!oppList}" var="opp">
                <apex:column>
                    <apex:outputlink>{!opp.Name}</apex:outputlink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!opp.id}" />
                <apex:column value="{!opp.StageName}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is a question of how various browsers handle key events and not really about Salesforce. Suggest you review these http://stackexchange.com/search?q=onkeypress+select and post a question there if you don;t find a good answer. You may have to add jQuery to insulate you from browser variations.

Comment: @KeithC I rarely suggest using jQuery for something this trivial.

Comment: @sfdcfox Fair comment. With or without jQuery there is no getting away from the need to test in a multiple browsers in case stuff like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292132/onkeypress-event-not-firing-in-ie is real.

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't need to be nearly that complex. Here's the code you might use:

```
function keypress(event) {
    if((event.charCode || event.keyCode || event.which) === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector("[id$=btnSearch]").click();
    }
}
```

Any browser that doesn't support this function probably isn't supported by salesforce.com anymore.

As a side note: if you're calling your code from JavaScript, you may as well use an actionFunction:

```
<apex:page controller="OnEnter">
    <script>
    function handle(event) {
        if((event.charCode || event.keyCode || event.which) === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            javaScriptAction();
        }
    }
    </script>
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!action}" name="javaScriptAction" reRender="form"/>
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedOption}" onkeypress="handle(event)">
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Test 1" itemValue="Test 1" />
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Test 2" itemValue="Test 2" />
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Test 3" itemValue="Test 3" />
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```